# How to deploy an Angular App with Capistrano

Tags: angularjs, capistrano3

I'm trying to deploy an Angular app using Capistrano following [this](http://howwedoapps.com/2014/04/03/deploy-angularjs-app-with-capistrano-on-the-cloud) tutorial. So in my Capfile I have the following:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

And in my `config/deploy` file I've got the following:

```
...
task :bower_and_npm_install do 
  on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
    within release_path do 
      execute :npm, "install"
      execute :bower, "install"
    end
  end
end
after :published, :bower_and_npm_install
...
```

When I try to deploy I get the following error:

```
[6ff53bb3] Command: cd /home/user/apps/myapp/releases/20151015095546 && /usr/bin/env npm install
DEBUG [6ff53bb3]  /usr/bin/env:
DEBUG [6ff53bb3]  npm
DEBUG [6ff53bb3]  : No such file or directory
```

I've tried the following:

```
...
execute "bash -c '. /usr/bin/npm && cd #{current_path} && npm install'"
...
OR
execute "/usr/bin/npm && cd #{current_path} && npm install'"
OR
execute "cd #{current_path} && npm install'"
```

And none of it worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This means that NPM is not installed on the server or is not in the deployment user's path.

If you ssh into the server and run `npm --version`, does it return anything?

You might want to try https://github.com/capistrano/npm/

Comment: It does return the nam version. When I run `which npm` I get `/usr/bin/npm` What I don't get is why Capistrano is looking for Node on `/usr/bin/env`

Comment: The reason for env is explained here: http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/

Comment: Hi Will. Thanks for your reply. I saw that post earlier. It does explain the reason but not how to fix it. I've the capistrano/node but I believe the module is out of date and it didn't work either